# How can I detect when a UITableView has been scroll past the very bottom/top?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I've got a view that has 3 tableView's. One is the "Main Table View", and then I have an 'Answers Table View' and 'Percentage Table View'.

When the screens loads, the Main Table View occupies the top 95% of the screen. The bottom of the screen is a UIView containing 2 buttons. "Answers" and "Percentage".

The way it works, is if I click "Percentage" it changes the height of the Main Table View to 0, and gives that height to the Answers Table View. This animates the "Answers/Percentage" View to the top, and reveals either the Answers or Percentage TableView below it.

Here's an example:

[image]

As you can see, I click on "Percentage" which animates it up. If you click on "Percentage" again it animates it back down.

However, what I want to do is if the "Answers/Percentage" view is at the bottom of the View, and the user scrolls the Main Feed UP reaches the very end of the tableView's contents (not just the end, but the end and a little bit more), I want to animate it up like in the .gif.

Similarly, if the "Answers/Percentage" is at the top, and the user scrolls the lower "Answers Table View" down past a certain point where there is no more data above, it will completely animate.

Also, I do not ever want the "Answers/Percentage" view to be in the middle, and showing a tableview both top and bottom. All one, or the other, but not a bit of both. Which I have right now.

What I need to know is... how can I detect if the user has scrolled past the very top or very bottom of the table view +30 pixels for example, to initiate my animation?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the contentOffset property of the table view.

```
if(tableView.contentOffset.y >= (tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height)) {
    // Start the animation
}
```

I haven't tested this, but let me know if it works.

Comment: I would also go with the `.contentOffset.y` approach. To include the 30 pixels "buffer" mentioned in the question it would have to say something like `tableView.contentOffset.y - 30.0f >= (tableview[...]`. And: to actually have a place to check the contentOffset in this way, the table view delegate can implement either `scrollViewDidScroll:` (if you want to animate immediately once the 30px threshold is passed) or `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:` (if you want to wait for the user to release the drag).

Comment: @sublimepremise This appears to work, the problem is, after I do the animation, I need to be able to remove the user touch from the top tableview. Is that possible? For example, what happens is they scroll to the bottom, and far enough, it animates up the bottom tableView. With the finger still on the screen, they can scroll the original tableview back to the top. Unseen for now. Then when they animate the top tableview back, it has been scrolled to the top instead of at the bottom where I want it. How can I kick/end their touch event when I do the animation?

Comment: @Gamma This appears to work, the problem is, after I do the animation, I need to be able to remove the user touch from the top tableview. Is that possible? For example, what happens is they scroll to the bottom, and far enough, it animates up the bottom tableView. With the finger still on the screen, they can scroll the original tableview back to the top. Unseen for now. Then when they animate the top tableview back, it has been scrolled to the top instead of at the bottom where I want it. How can I kick/end their touch event when I do the animation?

Answer (score 0):

Making another answer based on **sublimepremise**'s approach because it's easier to format and post code that way. The base idea is to check the table view's `.contentOffset.y`, e.g. by implementing `scrollViewDidScroll` in its delegate, and triggering your animations accordingly.

It may have a bit of a QnD feel to it, but if you need to also abort the user's dragging action when triggering the animation, an easy way to do so would be by "resetting" the table view's gesture recognizer. In code that could look something like this:

```
static const CGFloat kChrisTableViewAnimationThreshold = 30.0f;

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == self.topTableView) {
        if([self scrolledPastBottomThresholdInTableView:self.topTableView]) {
            // Start the animation
            // ...

            // Toggling the table view's pangGestureRecognizer off and on cancels the gesture
            self.topTableView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
            self.topTableView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)scrolledPastBottomThresholdInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return (tableView.contentOffset.y - kChrisTableViewAnimationThreshold >= (tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height));
}
```

Note that this illustration obviously only covers recognizing when the top table view is scrolled past its bottom end, but adapting it for handling other scenarios should be pretty straightforward.